# Error while using EntityAutoInc as a Dao generic in playframework

Tags: scala, shapeless

```
trait EntityAutoInc[PK, E <: EntityAutoInc[PK, E]] extends Entity[PK] { self: E =>
  import shapeless._
  import tag.@@
  import tag.$at$at

  def copyWithNewId(id : PK)(implicit mkLens: MkFieldLens.Aux[E, Symbol @@ Witness.`"id"`.T, PK]) : E = 
  {
    (lens[E] >> 'id).set(self)(id)
  }
```

This is the code pulled out from "PlayAuthenticate - usage sample application Play! Framework 2 (Scala)".

> I am getting an error "stable identifier required, but shapeless.Witness.selectDynamic("\"id\"") found."
>
> and
>
> "could not find implicit value for parameter mkLens: shapeless.MkFieldLens[E,Symbol with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String("id")]]
>   and
>
> not enough arguments for method >>: (implicit mkLens: shapeless.MkFieldLens[E,Symbol with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String("id")]])shapeless.Lens[E,mkLens.Elem]. Unspecified value parameter mkLens."

I  am new to scala and playframework so still in the process of learning. Can somebody help me to rectify this error.

Comment: Have you modified code in some way except for adding duplicated `import tag.$at$at`? When I get the last source from https://github.com/bravegag/play-authenticate-usage-scala it compiles perfectly well with sbt on my machine.

Comment: No i did not modify the code.